# gdal2tiles QGIS 3.10 not referenced properly

Tags: gdal, qgis-3, gdal2tiles, xyz-tiles

I processed virtual rasters with gdal2tiles. The output seems reasonable and it is displayed correctly on the generated output maps (Leaflet, Openlayers, Google). I then copied the tiles to a nginx webserver. This server I connected as XYZ in QGIS 3.10.

- The tiles are not at the correct geographic location.
- The order/arrangement of the displayed tiles is incorrect.
- QGIS crashes.

The input virtual rasters are in EPSG3857. The following GDAL command has been used:
`python3 -m gdal2tiles -p mercator -z 8 -w none -r average -s EPSG:3857 -a 0.0 C:/Users/usr/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_e4fd1fe4809945ec86e3d5caede62eaa/f7ff49e364cc4f3bb55dc2a7d5fae023/OUTPUT.tif X:\02_GIS\901_QGIS\QGISServer\tiles\smr`

Comment: Perhaps QGIS awaits OpenStreerMap style structure. Read the document https://gdal.org/programs/gdal2tiles.html#gdal2tiles and have a try with --xyz.

Comment: @user30184 Thank you. I did both but none of them solved the problem.